# how to have a sliding menu on the top of the page

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview

I am new to iphone programming. I was browsing through different apps at iTunes. Found this excellent menu. Can you folks help me to understand what is to be done technically to achieve this menu.

The user can slide this menu from left to right or vice versa without disturbing the view in the bottom. how to achieve this ? Thanks in advance

[alt text http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/039/Purple/ed/2d/d7/mzl.uawcjxjf.320x480-75.jpg](http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/039/Purple/ed/2d/d7/mzl.uawcjxjf.320x480-75.jpg)

[alt text http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/019/Purple/54/e1/08/mzl.usfrcvkh.320x480-75.jpg](http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/019/Purple/54/e1/08/mzl.usfrcvkh.320x480-75.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example helped me. http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-sliding-menu/

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.

Answer (score 1):

.h

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property ( nonatomic , retain )  IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender;

-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons;
```

.m

```
@synthesize scrollView;



-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom called");


    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;


    if (button.tag == 0) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked first button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
    }
    else if (button.tag == 1) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked second button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);

    }
    // ......like this

    NSLog(@"button clicked is : %iBut \n\n",button.tag);



}       



-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons{

for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfButtons; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with image

        //OR

    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%iBut",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title

    button.frame = CGRectMake(i*(offset+buttonSize.width), 8.0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);

    button.clipsToBounds = YES;

    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;//half of the width

    button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

    button.tag=i;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

}

self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake((buttonSize.width + offset) * totalNoOfButtons, buttonSize.height);

    //self.navigationItem.titleView=self.scrollView;//if u have navigationcontroller then enable this line
```

}

**Dont forget to connect the scrollView in interface builder**

**while creating the scrollview in IB make sure ur scrollView height is 44.which is default to navigation bar.so it will look nice.**

```
in viewDidLoad call 

[self createMenuWithButtonSize:CGSizeMake(70.0, 30.0) withOffset:20.0f noOfButtons:30];
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]