# how to create a sliding menu bar for buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

hi everyone  i am doing a application where i will be implementing sliding of buttons in a menu.something like slider which contains  many buttons.

i went through the following link

http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-sliding-menu/

In the above link they have set everything in Appdelegate method...whereas in my application there r many views which will continue further..so can anyone help me how to implement the sliding menu bar for buttons?

Thank u.

Comment: This is one [the question from stackoverflow...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156069/menu-over-slider-iphone-getting-the-x-co-ordinate-of-uislider-pointer-when-slid)

Comment: Hey are you looking something like this ? http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jsscrollabletabbar

Comment: @Devang yup i am looking something like tat but i dont wan label and all those..when i click the button it should move to respective screen..have tat source code?

Comment: Yes. You can modify that source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to have a sliding menu on the top of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731904/how-to-have-a-sliding-menu-on-the-top-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.h

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property ( nonatomic , retain )  IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender;

-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons;
```

.m

```
@synthesize scrollView;



-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom called");


    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;


    if (button.tag == 0) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked first button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
    }
    else if (button.tag == 1) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked second button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);

    }
    // ......like this

    NSLog(@"button clicked is : %iBut \n\n",button.tag);



}       



-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons{

for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfButtons; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with image

        //OR

    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%iBut",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title

    button.frame = CGRectMake(i*(offset+buttonSize.width), 8.0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);

    button.clipsToBounds = YES;

    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;//half of the width

    button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

    button.tag=i;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

}

self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake((buttonSize.width + offset) * totalNoOfButtons, buttonSize.height);

    //self.navigationItem.titleView=self.scrollView;//if u have navigationcontroller then enable this line



    }
```

**Dont forget to connect the scrollView in interface builder**

**while creating the scrollview in IB make sure ur scrollView height is 44.which is default to navigation bar.so it will look nice.**

```
in viewDidLoad call 

[self createMenuWithButtonSize:CGSizeMake(70.0, 30.0) withOffset:20.0f noOfButtons:30];
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot..but i am getting few errors in backgroundcolor,border color and all its coming not found on object type CAlayer..so wat i shd do to ?

Comment: #import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Dont forget to connect the scrollView in interface builder

Comment: ya i added but when irun it i am getting a blank screen..i dint get where i shd connect the scrollview?

Comment: from interface builder drag the uiscrollview then connect with ur scrollView ivar in .h file.take care.

Comment: for instant help http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/conversation/do-u-want-instant-help-for-ur-question-or-r-u-new-bee-to-iphone-ipad-develop

Comment: in the above example buttons r in rectangular..how to make it round button?i am not getting exact size to modify to circle

Comment: check this out.if it is usefule then u can vote me up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952755/how-to-create-a-round-button/6954024#6954024

Comment: That works but how can i make them specific to device size. For eg: ipad and iphone plus have larger screens to 5 buttons can add easily but on a small device they should scroll otherwise they can be equal width without any scrolling within the visible view.

Comment: my answer is out dated one. Apple has improved UIKit much better now. you can go for StackView of Apple:)

Answer (score 1):

Basically a sliding menu like the one you refer to is made up of a UIScrollView that contains the UIButtons as subviews. Set the contentSize of the scroll view to CGSizeMake(total width of buttons, height of one button) and enableScrolling to YES.

It might be a good idea to create a view controller to control the menu. This VC could both produce the scroll view and the buttons within, and serve as target for the button actions.

Comment: thank u for ur response...as i am new to iphone development i dont know much of it..can u tel bit more in detail or some examples